# How do I setup the initial entry point into the ArcGIS Geoservices REST API?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, arcgis-rest-api, mapproxy, geoservices-rest-api

I am trying to implement the ESRI REST API with a non-esri service (MapProxy). I am able to add my service to ArcCatalog 9.3 as an 'ArcGIS Server'. However, none of the sample layers are displayed when I connect.

URL:

```
http://host/services/arcgis/
```

Start response:

```
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'application/json')])
```

This returns JSON ([as in the example](http://services.arcgis.com/help/index.html?fsquery.html))

```
{
  "currentVersion": 1.0, 
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "Anaheim",
      "type": "FeatureServer"
    },
    {
      "name": "Switzerland",
      "type": "FeatureServer"
    },
    {
      "name": "USA",
      "type": "MapServer"
    }
  ]
}
```

**How do I successfully setup the initial entry point (Service Catalog) into the ArcGIS Geoservices REST API?**

Comment: Are you still using Arcgis server 9.3?  And where do you want to use the REST end point?  Normally the REST endpoint of a particular service is used In one of the webapis, or it is viewed in the browser to make sure everything is running as you expected.

Comment: Are you connecting as an Admin? Try making a user connection. I remember there being differences back in 9.3.

Comment: I am trying to implement the GeoServices REST API with a non-esri service (MapProxy). It was my understanding that I would be able to add this service to ArcGIS via 'Add ArcGIS Server'. However, looking at Fiddler it seems to be talking in SOAP and is not interested in my JSON.